# npm start does not work but debug works

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to run my nodejs application by typing `npm start` via the console in Visual Studio Code.

The port that I specified in the code is `port 3000` and I have checked that no process is using port 3000. It returns

```
[Function: ex]
Listening on 3000
Port 3000 is already in use
```

However, when I tried to run the debugging via Visual Studio Code, it works fine with Port 3000.

How can I fix this so that I can run it with `npm start` ?

Launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you can run you script with node instead of npm

Comment: we need some more details to help you. What is the npm start script? What is your listener launch code?

Comment: It's look like you are trying to open connection on the same port again, Could you please add the code as well?

Comment: node app.js works fine but why is npm start not working @MuhammadAli

Comment: @RobertMennell my launch.json script as updated above

Comment: `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000` run this command to see if anhy process in running on port 3000

Comment: @McRist netstat -ano | findstr :3000 shows nothing which i believe no process is running on port 3000

Comment: what is your npm start command?